# changing of object into datetime format

Tags: pandas, datetime, time, timestamp

I am currently working on google sheet by importing in python.When I import the sheet it was in object format and later I converted into float, but I try to change the format of Date column then it gives me an error.

Following is the Dataframe on which I have to work on

```
df.head()
Out[21]: 
                  Date Avg_Energy Avg_Voltage
1  24-06-2018 12-50-02    2452.93            
2  24-06-2018 12-50-03    2452.98      228.03
3  24-06-2018 12-50-04    2453.04       228.7
4  24-06-2018 12-50-05     2453.1       228.4
5  24-06-2018 12-50-06    2453.16      228.74
```

I have applied the following code to change it into datetime format

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

I provide me the following error

```
df2['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-22-0636e9d0e511>", line 1, in <module>
    df2['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

  File "C:\Users\Hussnain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 451, in to_datetime
    values = _convert_listlike(arg._values, True, format)

  File "C:\Users\Hussnain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 380, in _convert_listlike
    raise e

  File "C:\Users\Hussnain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 368, in _convert_listlike
    require_iso8601=require_iso8601

  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 492, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime

  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 739, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime

  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 733, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime

  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx", line 99, in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string

  File "C:\Users\Hussnain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 1356, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Hussnain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 648, in parse
    raise ValueError("Unknown string format:", timestr)

ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '24-06-2018 12-50-100')
```

Comment: You don't have the average voltage also!

Answer (score 1):

You have an unorthodox datetime format.  Use the `format` argument.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S')

0   2018-06-24 12:50:02
1   2018-06-24 12:50:03
2   2018-06-24 12:50:04
3   2018-06-24 12:50:05
4   2018-06-24 12:50:06
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

See http://strftime.org/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

On my end I tested just with:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

And it worked. Appears that you don't have the first `Avg_Voltage` value.

---

```
                  Date   Energy    Voltage
1  24-06-2018 12-50-02  2452.93  322323.00
2  24-06-2018 12-50-03  2452.98     228.03
3  24-06-2018 12-50-04  2453.04     228.70
4  24-06-2018 12-50-05  2453.10     228.40
5  24-06-2018 12-50-06  2453.16     228.74

1    2018-06-24 12:00:00-02:00
2    2018-06-24 12:00:00-03:00
3    2018-06-24 12:00:00-04:00
4    2018-06-24 12:00:00-05:00
5    2018-06-24 12:00:00-06:00
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

You may use:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S')
```

to achieve better format.